# Why doesn't body margin cause white border when background color is set for body?

Tags: css

By default body has an 8px margin. If I set a background color declaration for body, the entire page is filled with that color. Since margin is outside of the element, I expected that there would be a band of white around the outside. I thought maybe the margin was being added off screen but with Chrome dev tools I can see the margin is within the boundaries of the page. Why does the body margin work this way?

```
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `html` doesn't have a background color, it takes the same as the `body`. If you want a margin around the `body`, simply add

```
html {
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your browser takes the internal root color:**

[image: Use padding instead:]

The first color it can find is #ccc from body so html takes it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

**You need a separate color style for html which is different from body:**

```css
html {
    background: white;
}

body {
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

[image]

**However, because there is no content in body, so no height. 
We need to set height for both html and body to take 100% of your browser.**

```css
html {
    background: white;
}

body {
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

html,body{
  height:100%
}
```

Comment: *Your browser takes the internal root color:* this has nothing to do with backgrond. As you can see it's about *color* not *background-color*